# Calling Process and not waiting for it to finish

Tags: c#, printing, process, crystal-reports

I have a winforms program that monitors for new text files being saved in a folder. When it finds the file it reads it, writes the data to a SQL table, does some updates, then calls another program to print a report using Crystal Reports 2021.

Then it waits for the next file.

Here is a copy of the code

```
'System.Diagnostics.Process LOProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
LOProc.StartInfo.FileName = PSParmServicePGM;
LOProc.StartInfo.Arguments = PSGUID;
LOProc.Start();'
```

After about a week the server becomes unresposive, I am assuming it is a memory issue. If I log out and back in and start my program is works for another week, then I have to do the same thing over again.

I ran processmon and I do not see the 2nd program getting stuck.

But I am seeing the splwow64.exe growing.
The 2nd program prints to the networked print server directly. The printers are not installed on the server running the print job.

What is the proper way to call a 2nd program but not tie up the calling program waiting for the 2nd program to finish.

Comment: One suggestion, please use `using`

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to conclude that you are launching your processes improperly. It could be, for example, that your second process simply isn't exiting, which has nothing to do with the code shown here. I think you need a troubleshoot a little more.

Comment: Do you know what `splwow64.exe` is and does?

Comment: Splwow64.exe is a windows component to interop between x86 applications and x64 drivers. It should be short lived. If it's not and it's memory usage is growing in size, it's possibly an issue with the OS or the driver of the printer you're using. I note there's a hotfix for Server 2008 where the splwow64.exe process doesn't stop: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/splwow64-exe-process-doesn-t-end-after-a-print-job-finishes-in-the-64-bit-version-of-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2-c6a0c299-66d2-7d8c-0877-6ced0836269b.

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to consider using an x64 version of your app instead. In doing so, you won't spawn the splwow64.exe process at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Crystal Reports process closes and disposes the report object properly.

Comment: I am doing a close and dispose after it finishes printing.

Comment: I am noticing the splWOW64 goes back down after I close the 1st program, the one that is calling the program that does the printing.